# InfluxQL: how to read one value and its derivative

Tags: influxdb, influxql

I am stuck with an issue with InfluxDB.
I would like to show a value with its derivative.
If I try the following:

```
SELECT DERIVATIVE(value) FROM (SELECT value FROM MyValues WHERE "f"='myfield')
```

...I get the derivative values. If I try the following:

```
SELECT value, DERIVATIVE(value) FROM (SELECT value FROM MyValues WHERE "f"='myfield')
```

...I get an empty result. So apparently I cannot mix the derivative with the normal values?!

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Derivative returns the rate of change for the values in a single field in a series.

InfluxDB calculates the difference between chronological field values and converts those results into the rate of change per unit.

```
SELECT DERIVATIVE(<field_key>, [<unit>]) FROM <measurement_name> [WHERE <stuff>]
```

[image]
When you select the aggregate function then you can't select ValueField seperatly.

[Influxdb Derivative Reference](https://archive.docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v0.13/query_language/functions/#:%7E:text=DERIVATIVE(),-Returns%20the%20rate&text=InfluxDB%20calculates%20the%20difference%20between,rate%20of%20change%20per%20unit%20.&text=It%20then%20calculates%20the%20difference,rate%20of%20change%20per%20unit%20.)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply.
At the end I managed to get what I wanted with quite a complicated query:

```
SELECT value FROM
(SELECT MEAN(V) AS value, MEAN(D) AS Derivative FROM
(SELECT DERIVATIVE("value") as D FROM "MyValues" WHERE "f"='myfield' ),
(SELECT "value" as V FROM "MyValues" WHERE "f"='myfield')
GROUP BY time(1m) fill(none)
) WHERE Derivative!=0
```